# my project location is not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js

> I install node version 4.4.7 for Windows. I tired a sample project. while I run the project on installed nodes command prompts. I had the following error.

```
'E:\nodeexample\myproject' is not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program or batch file
```

> I tried setpath="c: /program files/nodejs" and some other answers suggestion here, but nothing helped me.

Comment: how did u try to run node?

Comment: like above said C;/> 'E:\nodeexample\myproject' (my project location) and enter it throws me that error .

Comment: that is not how u run a node project

Comment: then how to run my project .. can u suggest anything for this.

Comment: i made a mistake . after adding cd 'E:\nodeexample\myproject'  it works for me.